# How do I see the last 10 commits in reverse-chronological order with SVN?

Tags: svn, commit

Using the SVN command line, is there a way to show the last X number of commits along with commit messages, in reverse-chronological order (newest commit first)?

Answer (score 196, accepted):

```
svn log --limit 10
```

or

```
svn log -l 10
```

Further googling uncovered the answer. `svn log` lists in reverse-chronological order by default.

Comment: SVN has really useful built-in help.  `svn help log` would probably be even faster than a Google search.

Comment: This command seems to return only the last but one(not the latest) commit messages. For eg the latest commit is r901 but it returns only till r900. Just wanted to check if this was the standard or an error. Also `svn log -l10 <URL of your repository>` would return the latest(r901) also.

Comment: This isn't the right answer, this wont show the latest commits, and that could be very misleading.

Answer (score 28):

To clarify the previous answers - note that `svn log` by default only shows the commits up to the revision of your working copy (latest `svn update`, run `svn info` to see). So yes, if it's OK for you to download all commits first, this combination will work:

```
svn update

svn log -l 10
```

However, I'm mostly interested in showing the ALL latest commits without first updating my working copy, so I mostly compare my log to HEAD falling:

```
svn log -l 10 -r HEAD:1
```

It makes a huge difference to me.

Comment: The -r HEAD:1 is key.

Answer (score 24):

A shortcut `-l` exists for `--limit`

```
# show last 10 logs
svn log -l 10
```

Comment: It doesn't though. yegor256's answer is the correct one.

Answer (score 22):

To see them in chronological order:

```
svn log -r1:HEAD
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, the other answers don't show my latest commits.